# Cannot find spring application class in unit test class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, testing, spring-test

We are in the process of creating from the scratch product with spring webflux. We are writing our unit test cases. Though I can able to get the Spring Application main class in my import, when we run `mvn clean install`, it is keep on telling that `Compilation failure, cannot find class`. How we can overcome this?

My project structure is,

```
Application
     -app-web-module
        -src/java/com/org/SpringApplicationClass
        -pom.xml
     -app-web-unitcases
        -src/test/com/org/mytestclass
        -pom.xml
```

And my test class is,

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT=ci")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = com.org.MainApplication.class)
public class BaseACTest {


    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @BeforeAll
    public void init1() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(webTestClient);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAllAmenities() {
        webTestClient.get().uri("/urltobeplaced/1234")
            .header("X-Request-ID", "123")
            .header("X-Session-ID", "123")
            .header("X-Application-ID", "123")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk();
    }

}
```

Comment: The default structure for Maven projects is `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`. You should reorganize your code accordingly.

Comment: @RolandWeisleder Due to some project constraint, we had to create structure like this. Is there any way to access the springapplication class from outside of the module?

Comment: This question mostly related to the maven project organization. You should copy the source code (or compile jar and add as dependency) of `-app-web-module` to the `-app-web-unitcases` during test execution, by additional `pom.xml` maven configuration.